# Detect when a Mac OS X window is resized or moved

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am writing an application which must know when any window is resized or moved.
I have looked at notifications but it seems it does not do what I expected.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Give your window a delegate.  The [NSWindowDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) has `windowWillResize:toSize:` and `windowWillMove:` methods.

Comment: Does it work for all windows? I mean not only the one from the application?

Answer (score 2):

Given your response to Carl's answer, I'd suggest the [Accessibility API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html), which can give you access (and I believe frame change notifications) for all windows, not just your app's.

Comment: It's a good idea unfortunatly, notifications are raised when thing are done and not during moving or resizing :(

Comment: It is unfortunately the best you can do for other applications' windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want window size/ordering then take a look at CGWindow.h. CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray() is probably what you want.

NSWindowList() is also useful for a list of windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage MacOS Windows try using Accessibility.

AX very tricky (low level/ asyc) but these two githubs help a lot.

https://github.com/tmandry/Swindler

uses

https://github.com/tmandry/AXSwift

They provide callbacks for windows create and move etc.

Start with Swindler

Answer (score -1):

In Swift my AppDelegate looked like this:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Set NSWindowDelegate to respond to windowWillResize
    window.delegate = self
}

func windowWillResize(sender: NSWindow, toSize frameSize: NSSize) -> NSSize {
    println(frameSize)
    return frameSize
}
```

Comment: There is no window property in the AppDelegate class.

Comment: Then make sure the `AppDelegate` implements `NSWindowDelegate`.