# How to get notified when window order or position on Mac has changed?

Tags: cocoa

My program needs to observe changing in windows order and position. Like when some window gets above another or moves somewhere. Could it be performed with Cocoa (Window Services, Notification API)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect when a Mac OS X windows is resized or moved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017636/detect-when-a-mac-os-x-windows-is-resized-or-moved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these windows belong to your app?

If so then just register for the following notifications:
   NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification
   NSWindowDidResignMainNotification
   NSWindowDidMoveNotification
   NSWindowDidResizeNotification

If the windows don't belong to your app then you might have to use a timer.